# How to select max date from table for distinct values

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, max

I have a table that looks like this:

| date | account | asset | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2022 | 1 | A | 12 |
| 01-01-2022 | 1 | B | 100 |
| 02-01-2022 | 1 | A | 14 |
| 02-01-2022 | 1 | B | 98 |
| 01-01-2022 | 2 | A | 15 |
| 01-01-2022 | 2 | C | 230 |
| 02-01-2022 | 2 | A | 13 |
| 02-01-2022 | 2 | B | 223 |
| 03-01-2022 | 2 | A | 17 |
| 03-01-2022 | 2 | B | 237 |

I want to be able to get the last values (i.e. max date) for each account. So the result should look like this:

| date | account | asset | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02-01-2022 | 1 | A | 14 |
| 02-01-2022 | 1 | B | 98 |
| 03-01-2022 | 2 | A | 17 |
| 03-01-2022 | 2 | B | 237 |

How can this be done in SQL?

EDIT: Notice that the max dates for the different accounts are not the same.

Comment: `select * from table where date=(select max(date) from table) order by account,asset`

Comment: Sorry if my example is a little misleading. Not all accounts have the same date. I will edit my question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by first selecting the max dates for each account and then forcing the match between accounts given the date constraints, like in the following query:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
        MAX(date) AS date, 
        account
    FROM 
        tab 
    GROUP BY 
        account
    ) max_date_per_account
INNER JOIN 
    tab
ON 
    tab.date = max_date_per_account.date 
AND  
    tab.account = max_date_per_account.account
```